# Close a java-process in a controlled way, supply data to the running process

Tags: java, input, exit

I would like to stop a running Java-program in a controlled way.

I have started the program with a bash-script called with crontab and it runs on a Ubuntu server.

I want the Java-program to exit in a controlled way so not kill it.

I can't have an input-console and make it listen to a socket and send a packet to that socket to make it stop seems to much work and hard to do locally on the server.

Is there some other approach I can take on this problem?

Comment: I would suggest to use a socket and send a packet. When the program recieves the packet it will initiate its shutdown routine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop java process gracefully?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191215/how-to-stop-java-process-gracefully)

Comment: Listening to a socket and getting commands from it is a really piece of cake in java.
So it might be the least trouble.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191215/how-to-stop-java-process-gracefully . Shutdown hooks + standard kill is the way to go, tested on production :)

Comment: A related answer [Determine if an application is shutting down normally](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6214223/697630).

Comment: For me it would be best if I could control the program from a web page on the server (Apache), not sure if that is possible. I have looked into [Java Management](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/overview.html) as an alternative, but I leaning towards listening on socket.

Answer (score 0):

What You could do is create some kind of marker and poll it periodically.
For instance, create a temporary file and act if it gets deleted. Or created. Or gets some magic cookie written in it.
Or You might spawn a subprocess and work until that gets killed.
There is some discussion on catching UNIX signals in Java, but I never dug into it.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to indicate a java process to kill itself is

Create a flag in a config file or database field such as

> kill = false

Create a thread in your java process which polls on this config variable every second.

Once the flag is set to kill the process such as

> kill=true

You can release all the resources and exit.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is usefull for your purposes but you can call `System.exit(1);` when you want to stop a Java program; e.g. when user clicks on a button you call `System.exit(1);` in your Java code

Angelo