# flush printwriter on application close

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, interrupt-handling, shutdown-hook

So I have a printwriter that will occasionally write to a file ("occasionally" here meaning "periodically after a certain number of specified events").

Now if these events happen to be too few, the log file may end up empty when the application is terminated (`Ctrl + C`).

I could, of course, `flush` after every `println`, but that would defeat the purpose of having a non-auto-flush printwriter (which is the only kind that can be created anyway if I want to pass a `File` as a constructor argument).

Is there a `onApplicationKill`-thing in Java I could instrument to flush the writer once when the application is terminated? Or something to detect when the current thread is killed?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975248/java-how-to-handle-a-sigterm)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a shutdown hook:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
  public void run() {
      ...
      writer.flush();
  }
});
```

It should also work if you kill it with `Ctrl+C`