# How do I ignore SIGTERM and keep running in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

How do I ignore SIGTERM and **keep running** my program in Java? Please note that I am not looking at options for [graceful shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975248/how-to-handle-a-sigterm). I just want to ignore the SIGTERM.

Comment: Just to add: sun.misc.* package which have got signal handlers are not exposed in Oracle JDK but is available Open and AdaptOpenJDK.

Comment: "ignore the SIGTERM" is not really good behaviour. Most senders of SIGTERM will follow it with SIGKILL after some time. And a SIGKILL cannot be handled gracefully.