# Azure Spring Boot app receiving SIGTERM right after start

Tags: spring-boot, azure, sigterm

I have deployed a Spring Boot Application to Azure, which is up and running. For some reason, it suddenly receives a SIGTERM right after startup for the last couple of deployments, so the app actually never gets updated. I have no clue as to where to look for the actual cause of this behaviour, the SIGTERM seems to come out of nowhere from what I can tell. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975248/how-to-handle-a-sigterm?

Comment: Thank, no. But the issue is not how to handle a SIGTERM, but why the SIGTERM occurs in the first place.